# UITabbar UI issue in IOS 13 | XCode 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios13, tabbar

When I run the application in XCode 11.1, UITabbar unselected items are not visible as shown in image

[image: UITabbar UI Issue]

```
    UITabBarController *tController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"footerhover.png"];
    [tController.tabBar addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottombar.png"]]];
    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    ProfileViewController *pViewController=[[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    pViewController.tabBarItem.title=@"PROFILE";
    pViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_white.png"];
    pViewController.tabBarItem.tag = 1;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    }else{

        [pViewController.tabBarItem setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

        [pViewController.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_white.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    }
    UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pViewController];
    senderArray[0] = nav1;
    [arr addObject:nav1];
    tController.viewControllers=senderArray;
```

Tabbar is working fine in XCode 10.3 / IOS 12.
Please suggest any solutions to fix this issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `[tController.view insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottombar.png"]] belowSubview:tController.tabBar]`? Is this the real code? It's suspicious, because you're assigning array of strings to the `viewControllers` property, etc.

Comment: @zrzka edited my code. Please check it.

Comment: Did you try to move your bottom bar image view below the tab bar? (See first comment)

Comment: Yes. Partially it worked, can you make it as answer....! @zrzka

Comment: Partially? So something still doesn't work for you?

Comment: If I use, Navigation bar is not displaying....!

Comment: Made an answer from the comment. Re _navigation bar is not displaying_ - this is another, unrelated, question and it shouldn't be discussed in comments. Create a new question for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace this line ...

```c
[tController.tabBar addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottombar.png"]]];
```

... with ...

```c
[tController.view insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottombar.png"]]
                   belowSubview:tController.tabBar];
```

`addSubview` documentation:

> The view to be added. After being added, this **view appears on top of any other subviews**.